# How do I dismiss chain of view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a set of view controllers VC1, VC2, VC3, VC4.
VC2 has multiple entry points and can either be presented modally or pushed onto a navigation controller.

Currently I am in VC1. On some action, I present VC2 modally. Some subsequent actions in VC2 take me to VC3->VC4. There is a button in VC4 which should take me back to VC1.

How do I implement this in simple way? One way is to implement it through delegates. But do I need to set it in each of view controllers on the pathway?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no need to set any delegates.I have made demo upon your question and I found one solution.

Let's say You have 3 View controllers opening modally.

A - Starting view controller

A -> VC1

VC1 -> VC2

VC2 -> VC3

Just write this below line on button tap.

```
 self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

> P.S : Use presentingViewController property as many view controllers
>   you have. In my case I have written 3 times because I have modally
>   presented 3 view controllers.

Comment: Quick and easy solution. The only drawback is that interim view controllers might blink.

Answer (score 1):

Use unwind segues (If you are using storyboard)!

Read up on it in the apple docs and find some examples online. Your scenario is perfect for this.

Put this in your VC1 viewController (the one you want to return to):

```
@IBAction func backToVC1(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Then in the Storyboard in your last viewcontroller, control-drag from your button to the exit icon at the top of the viewController and choose backToVC1 from the pop-up.

This will dismiss the whole stack of viewcontrollers and bring you back to VC1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods to achieve this from a `UINavigationController` -

[image]

[Apple's Doc Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

Comment: popToRootViewController/popToViewController has to be implemented in VC1. To call it, VC4 has to call some delegate method like delegate.doneClicked(). So do I need to pass this delegate object from VC1->VC2->VC3->VC4?

Comment: is VC1 your rootViewController? You can use your AppDelegate to get the navigationController. Using `UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` you are able to retrieve your `AppDelegate` instance from any class.